# How use query() with WHERE clause?

Tags: android, sql, database, where-clause

I need to get the question, where the column : activity, lesson and screen are equal to eg: " 1", " 2" , "3".
Note: question is a column too.

My code should return a string = "4" but are returning:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@547e1a74
```

Code:

```
databaseHelper = Database.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

long id4 = databaseHelper4.insertData("1", "2", "3","4", "5", "6", "7", "8");
String question = databaseHelper4.getQuestion("1", "2", "2");
Message.message(IntroActivity.this, question);
```

Database:

```
public String getQuestion(String activity, String lesson, String screen){

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.QUESTION};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, DatabaseHelper.ACTIVITY +
    "=?" + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.LESSON + "=?" + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.SCREEN +
    "=?", new String[]{activity, lesson, screen}, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor.toString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
return cursor.toString();
```

`Cursor.toString()` method return String representation of Cursor instead of values which is contained by Cursor.

Get `QUESTION` Column value from cursor as:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
String question = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                               DatabaseHelper.QUESTION));
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of returning `cursor.toString()`, you should return

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.QUESTION));
```

after you call `cursor.moveToFirst();`

```
public String getQuestion(String activity, String lesson, String screen){

   SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
   String[] columns = {DatabaseHelper.QUESTION};
   Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, DatabaseHelper.ACTIVITY +
   "=?" + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.LESSON + "=?" + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.SCREEN +
   "=?", new String[]{activity, lesson, screen}, null, null, null, null);

     cursor.moveToFirst()
     return cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.QUESTION));;

}
```